# Symfony 1.4 propel schema.yml: how to set utf8 charset, utf8_collate_ci as collation?

Tags: php, symfony1, utf-8, propel

Everything is utf8 where it can, still when I see the table, I see the charset is `latin` and the collation is `latin_swedish_ci`. I want to set utf8 and utf8_collation_ci. How?

Comment: I'm pretty interested in getting this solved. Any luck, John?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your databases.yml you can set :

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb'
      username: myusername
      password: mypassword
      attributes:
        default_table_charset: utf8
        default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: thx for answering, but its "propel" :) and it ignored the charset properties